# CytoscapeJS network graph - Edges are not plotted

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, cytoscape.js, edges

I am facing a new issue with using ***CytoscapeJS***. I have a network graph with 300+ nodes and 300+ edges in a JSON object (can rise to *500+ nodes & 1000+* edges in some cases).

The nodes are getting plotted using *coLa* layout but only the 1st 50 edges are shown. The rest of the edges are missing from the generated network despite my setting the "**visibleDisplay**" property to "**element**". How can I resolve this ? (or is there a ***limitation*** to the no. of edges that can be plotted in CytoscapeJS ?)

Comment: Note: I have been working on reproducing the issue for datasets of varying sizes and am strangely also getting the same error (i.e., some edges between nodes aren't plotted at all) for smaller datasets as well (just 30-40 nodes). Any suggestions anyone ?

Comment: Please refer to your same question on the issue tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this **issue** is at [git_cytoscapejs_issues_779](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/779)

Answer (score 0):

For a small network graph with just 31 nodes, only 8 have edges plotted correctly despite the elements JSON file having no errors and specifying the source node, target node, node shape, colour, etc. correctly. Screenshot included below:
[image]

A working example showing this error can be seen at [jsbinCytoscapeJSEdgeError](http://jsbin.com/yikatiqela/1/edit?js,output)